# Seekbar didn't work correctly

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I want to get value from seekbar in my application every time I touch it. The value that I declared in seekbar will be added in my url but each time I touch the seekbar it gives me a looping and the url will loop and loaded as amount seekbar on `progressChanged`. This is my code:

```
int period = 0;
SeekTime.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (SeekTime.getProgress() <= 3){
            SeekTime.setProgress(0);
            period=7;
        }
        if (SeekTime.getProgress() > 3 && SeekTime.getProgress() <= 8) {
            SeekTime.setProgress(5);
            period =30;
        }
        if (SeekTime.getProgress() >8 && SeekTime.getProgress()<=13){
            SeekTime.setProgress(10);
            period = 90;
        }
        if (SeekTime.getProgress() >13 && SeekTime.getProgress()<=18){
            SeekTime.setProgress(15);
            period = 180;
        }
        if (SeekTime.getProgress() >18 && SeekTime.getProgress()<=23){
            SeekTime.setProgress(20);
            period = 270;
        }
        if (SeekTime.getProgress() >23){
            SeekTime.setProgress(25);
            period = 360;
        }
        new LoadData(URL+period).execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem that you get is because when you call SeekTime.setProgress() the progress is being changed - it calls onProgressChange() again.

What you should do is to check, if the progress change have been done by user. You have fromUser variable that allows you to control that.

```
int period = 0;
SeekTime.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
    boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(fromUser) {
    if (SeekTime.getProgress() <= 3){
        SeekTime.setProgress(0);
        period=7;
    }
    if (SeekTime.getProgress() > 3 && SeekTime.getProgress() <= 8) {
        SeekTime.setProgress(5);
        period =30;
    }
    if (SeekTime.getProgress() >8 && SeekTime.getProgress()<=13){
        SeekTime.setProgress(10);
        period = 90;
    }
    if (SeekTime.getProgress() >13 && SeekTime.getProgress()<=18){
        SeekTime.setProgress(15);
        period = 180;
    }
    if (SeekTime.getProgress() >18 && SeekTime.getProgress()<=23){
        SeekTime.setProgress(20);
        period = 270;
    }
    if (SeekTime.getProgress() >23){
        SeekTime.setProgress(25);
        period = 360;
    }
    new LoadData(URL+period).execute();
}
}
```

Comment: boolean fromUser is value from implement method for seekbar

Comment: I don't understand, could you explain it?

Comment: "You have fromUser variable that allows you to control that." fromUser is default variabel that i get when i implement method from seekbar. 

so there's no different between my code, and code that u wrote on your answer

Comment: Did you try this code? It is a default variable but I think it is only set to "true" on the first time (when user scroll the scrollbar). After, when you set the progress by setProgress it is set to false. Am I wrong? If yes, when this variable is set to false?

Comment: This is the reason why it is not working: "A callback that notifies clients when the progress level has been changed. This includes changes that were initiated by the user through a touch gesture or arrow key/trackball as well as changes that were initiated programmatically." Did you find a solution? I think you shouldn't change progress in onProgressChanged method, because this is the reason why it loops...

Comment: i didn't find a solution... how to  change progress in onProgressChanged method?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30724/discussion-between-marek-and-aoyama-nanami)